# cron ignoring environment variables?

Tags: unix, cron

This should be simple, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I have a very simple script run by cron:

```
export MAILTO=foo@foo.com
MAILTO=foo@foo.com
echo "MAILTO is set to $MAILTO"
```

Cron, however, seems to not be picking up the MAILTO variable - the cron e-mails look, in part, like this:

```
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/deploy>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=deploy>
Date: Thu, 20 Sep 2012 13:05:01 -0700

MAILTO is set to foo@foo.com
```

What am I missing?  Why isn't cron picking up the environment variables set in the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process in Unix can change its own environment variables and can define its children's environment variables when those children are created. A process cannot change its parent's environment variables, those of its children after those children are created, or those of any other process.

It appears as though you're trying to have a cron job change cron's environment variables, which is impossible.

Comment: Uh, ok...  so how on earth do I set MAILTO?  There seem to be a whole bunch of wrong "tutorials" out there.

Comment: @cbmanica: You haven't said why you want to change `MAILTO`, so I can't tell you how to do it.

Comment: I thought it was obvious that I wanted the output log e-mails to go someplace other than the owner of the crontab in question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're not logged in as the same user the cron is running under. Hence, creating the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

Set `MAILTO` environment variable in the `crontab` file. `cron` just ignore environment variables for security reason. If `MAILTO` is not specified, then the output will be mailed to the owner of the process that produced the output.